# Inconsistent matching with XSLT match

Tags: 2010, xslt

Would appreciate any guidance. I have a list, which includes three columns, listed in the XSLT snippet. I can't get the "Scope Risk" aka "Scope_x0020_Risk" column to match, but the others match and behave as expected. It seems as if it should be straight-forward, but it is not.

```
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp" version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl msxsl ddwrt" 

xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" 

xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 

xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
    <xsl:include href="/_layouts/xsl/main.xsl"/>
    <xsl:include href="/_layouts/xsl/internal.xsl"/> 

    <xsl:template name="FieldRef_body.Scope_x0020_Risk" match="FieldRef[@Name='Scope_x0020_Risk']" mode="body">
        <xsl:param name="thisNode" select="."/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$thisNode/@*[name()=current()/@Name] = 'Green'">
                    <img src="/_layouts/images/IMNON.png"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$thisNode/@*[name()=current()/@Name] = 'Amber'">
                    <img src="/_layouts/images/IMNIDLE.png"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <img src="/_layouts/images/IMNBUSY.png"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="FieldRef_body.Schedule_x0020_Risk" match="FieldRef[@Name='Schedule_x0020_Risk']" mode="body">
        <xsl:param name="thisNode" select="."/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$thisNode/@*[name()=current()/@Name] = 'Green'">
                    <img src="/_layouts/images/IMNON.png"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$thisNode/@*[name()=current()/@Name] = 'Amber'">
                    <img src="/_layouts/images/IMNIDLE.png"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <img src="/_layouts/images/IMNBUSY.png"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="FieldRef_body.Resource_x0020_Risk" match="FieldRef[@Name='Resource_x0020_Risk']" mode="body">
        <xsl:param name="thisNode" select="."/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$thisNode/@*[name()=current()/@Name] = 'Green'">
                    <img src="/_layouts/images/IMNON.png"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$thisNode/@*[name()=current()/@Name] = 'Amber'">
                    <img src="/_layouts/images/IMNIDLE.png"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <img src="/_layouts/images/IMNBUSY.png"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Some troll gave you a -1 without saying why.  Your question isn't so bad as that, I think.

Comment: Thanks for the support, BGM. XSLT can be a bit numbing at times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fault.  After stepping away and stabbing again:
I went into Designer and viewed the code for the webpart and saw that some of the column names were different from their titles when viewing the column information through a web browser. A person must have changed the column names, but the column names when view in teh code through designer didnt' actually change.

Comment: If this fixed it, you should mark your thread solved.

Comment: Ah, yes, anytime there is a space in the title name, it gets swapped with `_x0020_`.  Also, if someone renames the column titles using the Sharepoint GUI, the code-behind names don't get switched along with it.  Firebug is our friend!